# A pair of macros to make comment causes error in nested using

Tags: macros, comments

I construct a pair of macros -- `\cmton` and `\cmtoff` -- to comment `long codes block`.

They works all right except that another `\cmtoff` in a pair of `\cmton...\cmtoff`causes error, as the following example shows.

How to improve my design to make `\cmton \cmtoff` can be nested used.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\long\def\cmton#1\cmtoff{\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
Usage 1:
|\cmton
This works all right
\cmtoff|

Usage 2:
pre comment\\
\cmton
outer 1
  \cmton %nested
    inner
  \cmtoff %nested. Another \cmtoff nested in \cmton...\cmtoff causes error.
outer 2
\cmtoff 
post comment
\end{document}
```

Comment: better to use of latex syntax `\begin{comment}` see packages such as `comment.` Apart from not nesting a macro argument can not comment errors such as an unmatched `{` Better still is to use `%` any tex editor should let you comment or uncomment a region

Comment: @David Carlisle (1) It seems that `comment` environment can not be nested either.(2) In my project, a block of codes need being there  or being commented according to a logical condition. Purely using `\if ...\else...\if` may causes error when `\if...\fi` is in the block of code. That's why I need a tool to comment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to use latex syntax.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{cmt}{+b}{}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
Usage 1:
|\begin{cmt}
This works all right with 
\end{cmt}|

Usage 2:
pre comment\\
\begin{cmt}
outer 1
  \begin{cmt} %nested
    inner
  \end{cmt} %nested. Another \cmtoff nested in \cmton...\cmtoff causes error.
outer 2
\end{cmt}
post comment
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderfule solution! And should the argument be `+b` instead of `b`?

Comment: @lyl er yes, probably, I'll change

Comment: When I use the environment `cmt` by another way `\cmt ... \endcmt`, the typeset shows that the content of post this environment(here is the text "post comment" in Usage 2) disappeared. Why and how to make `\cmt ... \endcmt` work normally?

Comment: @lyl see my first line: it's better to use latex environment syntax here. the nesting relies on that as it is matching begin and end

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand why you'd want comments inside comments.

What's the problem? That your `\cmton`, defined by

```
\long\def\cmton#1\cmtoff{\ignorespaces}
```

(the code in the question seems to have been wrongly copied) will absorb everything up to the *first* `\cmtoff` token at the same brace level as `\cmton`, because TeX does *no* interpretation whatsoever of tokens absorbed as part of an argument to be supplied to a macro.<sup>*</sup>

You can check whether `\cmton` is in the argument. This allows one level of nesting.

But you're using the wrong approach to TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cmton #1 \cmtoff
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { \cmton } { \cmton } { \ignorespaces }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Usage 1:
|\cmton
This works all right
\cmtoff|

Usage 2:
pre comment
\cmton
outer 1
  \cmton %nested
    inner
  \cmtoff %nested. Another \cmtoff nested in \cmton...\cmtoff causes error.
outer 2
\cmtoff 
post comment

Usage 3:
Again
\cmton
outer
 {\cmton inner\cmtoff}
outer
\cmtoff
post

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, please, don't ask why further nesting doesn't work…

**Footnote**
<sup>*</sup> TeX will raise errors when finding `\par` as part to the argument to a non `\long` macro, or when finding `\outer` tokens (which aren't used in LaTeX).

Comment: Beautiful solution! Thank you! I have just corrected my wrong copied code that you pointed out. And, you mentioned `\outer` in the part of "Footnote". What's the meaning? What's the meaning and where does it come from?

Comment: @lyl Check the TeXbook or TeX by Topic if you're interested.